# Phpmyadmin doesn't work with other user than www-data?

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

I've changed the user+group where apache is running to my user name so I don't have to change the web files I'm editing. But now I get NoDataReceived error trying to import using phpmyadmin.

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_1.16

What can I do to avoid this problem?

When I change back in /etc/apache2/envvar to www-data for user and group it works to import the same file to the same db. I login to phpmyadmin as root.

Comment: One of us is completely confused.  I've never run into any problems with the standard setup; what is the problem you're trying to solve in the first place.  The link you provided doesn't seem to have anything to do with ownership at all.  Is your database very large?  If so, you just need to either split it, or compress it using the built-in compression abilities of phpmyadmin (I do this all the time, and have never had a problem).

Comment: Why not simply add the permissions for write for your user or any user?

Comment: I can't comment on @Giovanni Toraldo answer so I am writing here, I made the change for owner. No I need to take it back. Who is original owner:group for /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp ? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit */etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf*:

```
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

to a writable folder for your user.

Or change ownership of that folder:

```
chown user:user /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```